# Creating a batch file to move my current wallpaper?

Tags: batch-file

I'm an intermediate-novice to programming batch files, and I need some help. I currently have my wallpaper cycling through my Cool Pictures folder, but not all of these pictures make good wallpapers. Is it possible to create a .bat that, when run, will move the current wallpaper to a different folder, thus removing it from the rotation?

Thanks!

Comment: *Yes.* Have you tried anything so far??

Comment: Nothing successful. I'm pretty rookie to this.